# Changing the content of one node reflecting in other node created using node clone

Tags: 7, nodes

I used node clone to create similar contents. After creating the content using node clone, I have disabled and uninstalled node clone module.

Now, whenever I try to modify something in the cloned content or original node, both are getting reflected with the recent changes. Why is this happening? How do I resolve this?

Note: *I have uninstalled the module and cleared performance cache many times now*. Weird thing is, these changes are applying only to field collection fields.

Comment: I can't answer your question directly - but I had a similar problem with cloned content + images and translations.
I uninstalled the clone module and used the firefox extention Lazarus to simply recover an old form. But that won't work for nodes that you created longer time ago - not sure about your requirements, for us it's a good workaround.

Comment: Thanks. But the node is created long ago.. only now I realized the changes are reflecting all over the contents. I have uninstalled the module and cleared all the cache's that i'm aware of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with using node clone on node which uses field collection is, it preserves entity reference.

> The group of fields is simply an entity. When you use node clone to
>   clone a node the reference to the entity is preserved.
>
> *Quoting from [this article](https://drupal.org/node/1233256).*